# Sessions variables not available on ther pages.

Tags: php, session

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Session variables from page one are not available at page 2.

Notes: Page1 and page two are not in the same folder.

Page 1.

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
$_SESSION['TestSession'] = 'Available';
?>
```

Page 2.

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
echo "Your session variable is ".$_SESSION['TestSession']; 
?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `echo ini_get('session.cookie_path');`?

Comment: Do you have any code before `<?php  session_start();` ? You don't have to html before (don't write html comments before, nor spaces, and don't call 'echo' before `session_start();` etc...).

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: Is the SESSION variable available on page 1 after a refresh? It should be.

Comment: Your code is perfect. Its working. Check your session path

Comment: this 'echo ini_get('session.cookie_path');' shows a slash.

Comment: @PeeHaa , nah how do i get error reports?

Comment: to get it: `ini_get('error_reporting')`. to set it, either in php.ini, either in php file: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); session_start();` you can chose the degree of reporting, E_ALL is the most detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this is a UTF-8 BOM (Byte-Order-Mark) issue. If windows environment is accessible you can use Notepad++ to remove the BOM:

Open the file in notepad++
In Encoding menu select "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM"
Then save

Pages are not in same folder, but are they on same domain or subdomain???

Comment: I'm using localhost on wamp i don't know if that may be a domain issue. Can this have an effect?

Comment: on live site it should have effect but on localhost shouldn't. Also you should check your session path in php.ini

Comment: Checked it, here. session.cookie_path = /

Comment: Actually it was a few things BOM included. Thanks.